# WSO2 Data Services Server with Oracle OLAP Cube

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

Does anyone know how to integrate an Oracle OLAP Cube with WSO2 DSS?

I've tried looking for resources (google, forums, etc) about it but I haven't been able to find anything.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I personally haven't tried it, but it seems, you can use standard SQL for this task, as it is mentioned here http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_OLAP#Direct_SQL_Access. So if SQL is supported, then in DSS also, in the usual way, you just have to create a RDBMS data source mentioning the Oracle JDBC driver, and create a data service query with the required SQL.

Cheers,
Anjana.